# Reading in information into arrays

Tags: javascript, html

Say that I have the following information stored in a file subsysteminformation.txt

```
#{
    "buildnames": {
        label: "buildnames",
        data: ["test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4",
               "test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4",
               "test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4",
               "test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4",
               "test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4",
               "test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4",
               "test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4",
               "test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4/"
        ]
        }}; 


#{
    subsystem: "CAS",
  date: {
        label: "CAS",
        data: [null]
    },        
    time: {
        label: "CAS",
        data: [null]
    },
   modules: {
        label: "CAS",
         data: [null]
    }, 
    cases: {
        label: "CAS",
         data: [null]
    }, 
    failed: {
        label: "CAS",
                   data: [[0, 239], [1, 249], [2, 237], [3, 192],[4, 234], [5, 288], [6, 234], [7, 195],[8, 245], [9, 181], [10, 294], [11, 195],[12, 249], [13, 235], [14, 262], [15, 155],
          [16, 245], [17, 121], [18, 372], [19, 195],[20, 255], [21, 231], [22, 332], [23, 195],[24, 225], [25, 271], [26, 272], [27, 195],[28, 255], [29, 131], [30, 332], [31, 165],
          [32, 245], [33, 201], [34, 132], [35, 195],[36, 245], [37, 211], [38, 232], [39, 195],[40, 245], [41, 231], [42, 262], [43, 195],[44, 245], [45, 261], [46, 252], [47, 155],
          [48, 245], [49, 161], [50, 172], [51, 195],[52, 245], [53, 241], [54, 212], [55, 195],[56, 245], [57, 211], [58, 232], [59, 195],[60, 245], [61, 201], [62, 232], [63, 155],
          [64, 245], [65, 231], [66, 232], [67, 195],[68, 245], [69, 211], [70, 232], [71, 195],[72, 245], [73, 231], [74, 232], [75, 195],[76, 245], [77, 231], [78, 232], [79, 145],
          [80, 245], [81, 231], [82, 232], [83, 195],[84, 245], [85, 231], [86, 232], [87, 195],[88, 245], [89, 171], [90, 132], [91, 195],[92, 245], [93, 231], [94, 232], [95, 135],
          [96, 245], [97, 181], [98, 302], [99, 195],[100, 245], [101, 214], [102, 252], [103, 195],[104, 255], [105, 261], [106, 262], [107, 195],[108, 205], [109, 311], [110, 232], [111, 135],
          [112, 245], [113, 231], [114, 242], [115, 195],[116, 245], [117, 231], [118, 232], [119, 195],[120, 245], [121, 211], [122, 223], [123, 195],[124, 235], [125, 231], [126, 312], [127, 135]
          ]
    }, 
    cover: {
        label: "CAS",
         data: [[0, 235], [1, 239], [2, 237], [3, 192],[4, 234], [5, 288], [6, 234], [7, 195],[8, 245], [9, 181], [10, 294], [11, 195],[12, 249], [13, 235], [14, 262], [15, 155],
          [16, 245], [17, 121], [18, 372], [19, 195],[20, 255], [21, 231], [22, 332], [23, 195],[24, 225], [25, 271], [26, 272], [27, 195],[28, 255], [29, 131], [30, 332], [31, 165],
          [32, 245], [33, 201], [34, 132], [35, 195],[36, 245], [37, 211], [38, 232], [39, 195],[40, 245], [41, 231], [42, 262], [43, 195],[44, 245], [45, 261], [46, 252], [47, 155],
          [48, 245], [49, 161], [50, 172], [51, 195],[52, 245], [53, 241], [54, 212], [55, 195],[56, 245], [57, 211], [58, 232], [59, 195],[60, 245], [61, 201], [62, 232], [63, 155],
          [64, 245], [65, 231], [66, 232], [67, 195],[68, 245], [69, 211], [70, 232], [71, 195],[72, 245], [73, 231], [74, 232], [75, 195],[76, 245], [77, 231], [78, 232], [79, 145],
          [80, 245], [81, 231], [82, 232], [83, 195],[84, 245], [85, 231], [86, 232], [87, 195],[88, 245], [89, 171], [90, 132], [91, 195],[92, 245], [93, 231], [94, 232], [95, 135],
          [96, 245], [97, 181], [98, 302], [99, 195],[100, 245], [101, 234], [102, 232], [103, 195],[104, 245], [105, 231], [106, 232], [107, 195],[108, 245], [109, 301], [110, 232], [111, 135],
          [112, 245], [113, 231], [114, 242], [115, 195],[116, 245], [117, 231], [118, 232], [119, 195],[120, 245], [121, 211], [122, 223], [123, 195],[124, 235], [125, 231], [126, 312], [127, 135]
          ]
    }};
```

And the following script to read in the information.

```
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


function myFunction(){
    loadXMLDoc("subsysteminformation.txt",handleXML);
}
var checkState = function(xmlhttp, callback) {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    callback();
  } else {
    // Check back again 1 sec later
    setTimeout(checkState, 1000);
  }
};


function handleXML()
  {
checkState(xmlhttp, function() {
   var txt=xmlhttp.responseText;
   var datasets = [];
   var datasetsCounter =0;
   var secondPos;
   var aPosition;
   var currentCharacterLocation;
while(txt.indexOf("#") > -1){   
    aPosition = txt.indexOf("#");
    secondPos = txt.indexOf("#", (aPosition)+1);
    aPosition++;
    datasets[datasetsCounter]=txt.substring(aPosition, secondPos);
    //var stringToCompare = txt.substring(aPosition, secondPos);
    txt = txt.substring(secondPos);
    datasetsCounter++;
    document.write("done");
```

}

```
});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

Now to my problem

this section is terribly wrong

while(txt.indexOf("#") > -1){
        aPosition = txt.indexOf("#");
        secondPos = txt.indexOf("#", (aPosition)+1);
        aPosition++;
        datasets[datasetsCounter]=txt.substring(aPosition, secondPos);
        //var stringToCompare = txt.substring(aPosition, secondPos);
        txt = txt.substring(secondPos);
        datasetsCounter++;
        document.write("done");
}

What I want to do is to check if there are any more "#" characters in the text file, and if so read everything after (until the next "#" character or until there are no more characters at all in the document) into the array datasets[i], but I never get past the first #, perhaps some of you bright fellows out there could assist me in what I'm doing wrong, what shall I write instead of "if(txt.indexOf("#")" to check if there are any more "#" characters in the subsysteminformation.txt file?

Also how do I read in the last bit of information when there are no more "#" characters in the text?

Thanks in advance =)

**EDIT I'ts a plus if the sollution is fast since I will have approx 100 "#" characters in the file subsysteminformation.txt =)**

**EDIT 2 The problem is that I never get out of the "While" loop, it just keeps on going and going, I just want that as soon as one "#" character has been used, just move on to the next, don't reuse the same "#" character again. =)**

Comment: Other people may close your question as "too localized" if you do not narrow it down so people can tell what is being asked, what the main issue is, etc. I bet you don't need most of this code, and it is too long to skim.

Comment: @ninjagecko The problem is that I never get out of the "while" loop, it just keeps on going

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like this

> var dataset = xmlhttp.responseText.match(/^#(.[^;]*)/gm).map(function(item) { return eval("(" + item.replace(/^#/,'') + ")") })

then dataset will be an array of evaluated objects from your text file

Comment: @TheBrain I'm sorry can you please again take a quick look at that line, it says that it expects another ')', and when I'm adding it like this 

var datasets = xmlhttp.responseText.match(/^#(.[^#]*)/gm).map(function(item) { return eval("(" + item.replace(/^#/,'') + ")"}));

It still complains (expects another ')', what am I'm doing wrong? I know this is a stupid question :P

Comment: yes, sorry var dataset = xmlhttp.responseText.match(/^#(.[^#]*)/gm).map(function(item) { return eval("(" + item.replace(/^#/,'') + ")") })

Comment: @Adam, you may need to change the match() rule to /^#(.[^;]*)/ Otherwise you will have eval("({name:value};)") and it throws an error. If you read everything up to ';' then it should work just fine.

Comment: @TheBrain Sorry yet again, but now it says "object dosn't support this property or method, is what you're doing legal?  You can check it here [link](http://www.tdsoft.se)

Comment: @Adam I have a better suggestion for you. Instead of having multiple objects in the same file separated by # why not have an array of objects. For example the content of your file could be [{subsystem:''......}, {subsystem:''.....}, {subsystem:''...}]. Then on ajax response just make it var dataset = eval("(" + xmlhttp.responseText + ")");

Comment: @TheBrain What type will it be if I do like that, will it still be an array?